# Processing still image in realtime using GPUImage

Tags: uikit, ios7, gpuimage

Is it possible to process still image that is visible in view's content only without making processed UIImage copy of it? For example I have 8 megapixel image in fullscreen view pinched to actual pixels, I want to process only what's on the screen. Basically I want a "viewport" that processes it's content (image in most cases) in real-time.

Thanks,
Toto

Answer (score 0):

Sure. What you'll want to do is create a GPUImagePicture from your source image, then target that to a GPUImageCropFilter, with the result going to the filter you want to apply, and then the result of that to a GPUImageView.

The crop filter will let you zoom in on a particular region of your image, and only those pixels will be sent to your postprocessing filter for display. Going directly to a GPUImageView will be the fastest display path you have.

As the settings of your filter changes, or the cropped region of your source image does, you'll want to call `-processImage` on the GPUImagePicture to propagate those updates through the filter chain. Depending on the size of the image remaining in your cropped region, the device you're running on, and the intensity of the filters you're trying to apply, this should give you the realtime performance you desire.